# inner join based on over 100 attributes

Tags: sql, inner-join

I want to perform an INNER JOIN based on all columns. I know you can do:

select * from table_a INNER JOIN table_b on (table_a.name = table_b.name)

to perform an inner join based on both tables' `name` attribute. However if I have over 100 attributes. Is there an easier way instead of writing each attribute to do the comparison?

Comment: Doing a join on every column in both tables is a very unusual requirement; it suggests you want only records that exist identically in both tables A and B. Is that correct? Because there may be better ways to achieve this. What are you actually trying to do with the result of this query?

Answer (score 5):

All columns should have the same value?
So, in this case, why dont you use a INTERSECT way?

```
Select c1, c2, c3 from t1
INTERSECT
Select c1, c2, c3 from t2
```

It will return all records with all identical columns on both tables for you.

If you need some extra field you can use the same solution as a subquery.

It don't know your needs. It help you?

Comment: Good suggestion (+1), but INTERSECT is not supported in all major DBs; MySql, for instance. The OP didn't tag the question with a specific RDBMS, so it's hard to know if this will work for him.

Comment: I agree with you. It will depend on database used. If it is really needed, use hash is a good way too, like you suggested, but it should be dynamic, like function based indexes if the database supports. Otherwise the application should have this control. We should use the guns that we have.

Comment: if it helps, i am using nzsql

Comment: This only returns the join columns, no other columns. This is a very specialized solution that must be completely rewritten when one additional column is needed.

Comment: @usr If you need other columns too, this solution can be applied as a subquery. I don't know the nature of the problem, I just wanna help him with a possible solution.

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't. I advise you to write yourself a small query to generate this T-SQL code. It use dynamic SQL outright.

Answer (score 2):

If you honestly have to check all 100 columns to ensure a unique join, then that's the only way, and the only way to speed this process is to have the computer generate the raw SQL somehow. Most management interfaces for SQL that I know of don't support this kind of thing.

If this join is to be performed many times, then I would recommend finding or making a column in both databases that is guaranteed to be unique and that you can use to join on fewer columns. If the data is relatively static, and a join found now is expected to remain valid indefinitely, then I would generate a GUID in one DB and copy the values over to the other DB based on the 100-column join; that way, you only have to do the expensive join once. Making that column an index of both tables will further speed future queries.

It is also possible to compute a hash digest of the record; ideally, if two fields differ between two records, they'll have a different hash. This has the advantage that both systems can independently compute hashes; if they use the same algorithm and the same input, they'll get the same answer.

If you honestly have a 100-column "candidate key" between two tables, you have a fundamental failure in database design. Either these 100 columns shouldn't be in the same table, because a subset of them represent an entity at some higher level of abstraction in the real-world model which can be uniquely referenced in the "child" records of a second table, or else this collection of data describes some entity that can be given a single independently-unique identifier.

Comment: my guess is he's either comparing a current table with an archive/historical/log table or comparing data entry done more than once, by the same person on different days or by different people.  If he's comparing current and historical data, he could use a timestamp, and if he's comparing duplicate data entry, he could iterate through the 100+ fields for differences.  Not sure what he's doing, though, so no one can suggest appropriate alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
c1, c2, c3 
FROM t1 
INTERSECT 
SELECT 
c1, c2, c3 
FROM t2
```